# wrong fingerprint generation for assets with rails 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, asset-pipeline, unicorn

Setup: Rails 4.2.5, Ubuntu 12.04, nginx 1.6, unicorn 5, capistrano 2.15

The setup did work with Rails 3.2 but once i started to migrate to rails 4.x i noticed an odd behaviour with the assets.

Inside the application the links to the asset files like application.js are not the ones inside the manifest.yml

If i do a deploy with asset cleanup, i will get many 404. The fingerprints used by the app and the manifest.yml differ.
If i do right away a second deploy without a cleanup, the assets will be served. They wont match with the manifest again, but the old ones are still in the folder. Killing unicorn and making a full restart did not change anything.
I have the same problem in the 4.0 and 4.1 branch of my app.

The assets are compiled on the server during deploy (capistrano scripts)

update:
I checked via console which fingerprints are generated and which files are present. Result: hashes are fine.

Problem is that the cleanup script deletes files older than a week or something and when doing a deploy (asset precompile) i get a wrong timestamp for some files.

If i do a precompile just now, some files have a datestamp 4th January and get deleted by the following cleanup script. Capistrano shows me some warning when writing that file but without any meaningfull information

Comment: i was having a similar issue once where a gem ordered files from a folder differently on MAC vs LINUX. because of that the production app was generating different hashes. so you could try generating the manifest on the deployment server and on the production server and compare the results.